# Is there any framework for Tizen TV web application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I try to create a Tizen application for Tizen TV, I know we have two way to do this,that is `.NET` app and web app and I choice using web tools.

But I scare if I have no any architecture or framework, just only `html`, `css`, `JS` then I can not handle app when it go to big size.

Any suggestion do to this? any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOAST is based on cordova and unfortunately you will have to deal with CSS, JS and HTML. But you will get lot of extra functionalities to build a multiplatform apps due the main point of TOAST is to act as a proxy between your app and the TV, so every operation in TOAST is translated to the correct system function. You can check the TOAST wiki to get a complete list of methods and its compatibility with the supported platforms (browser, LG webos, Samsung Tizen, Samsung Legacy (orsay))

A more formal framework for Tizen would be CAPH:

CAPH is a Web UI framework for TV. Develop High Performance Web Application Easily and Quickly. CAPH consists of below modules.

- Key Navigation
- Scrollable List and Grid
- UI Components : Button, Radio Button, Toggle Button, Checkbox, Input, Dialog, Context Menu, Dropdown Menu
- Touch feature : Pan, Tap and Double Tap. (from CAPH 3.1)

Please find more info about CAPH [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/caph-30)

Comment: awesome ! that's so much helpful info for me, thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

[TOAST](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/toast/) is a newly launched feature for TV Web Application developer. For more framework visit [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv).

Comment: thank you so much, I will check your answer and accept it later

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/) to develop your application. It will make your life easier and faster.
[Bootsrtap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) works very well with Tizen TV and it will also help with scaling issues with some TV models.

For creating lists to display media files (like Netflix or Youtube applications) you can use [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). It works well and smoothly.

P.S. [Caph](https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/caphdocs/main.html?type=angular&doc=tutorial&p1=0) can work with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)